# How to fix NextJS build errors with 404 and 500 pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do we run `npm run build` on a NextJS app without having the /404 and /500 path errors?

`pages/_errors.tsx`

```
function Error({ statusCode }: any) {
  return (
    <p>
      {statusCode
        ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
        : "An error occurred on client"}
    </p>
  );
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }: any) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  return { statusCode };
};

export default Error;
```

`pages/404.tsx`

```
export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404</h1>;
}
```

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

`pages/500.tsx`

```
export default function Custom500() {
  return <h1>500</h1>;
}
```

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Super basic 404 and 500 pages. No matter what I change , `npm run build` refuses to build and states the following:

```
Build error occurred

Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /404
        /500
```

Both 404 and 500 are in the pages folder.

Comment: can you delete _errors page and just check, with 404 and page s ?

Comment: @RanuVijay I deleted the _error.tsx file and still the same build error.